# Selecting more than one column to query in sql

Tags: sql, select, pivot

I am having a bit of trouble, probably from my understanding of SQL. Here is the SQL I am currently using:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp 
(
    sPropertyCode VARCHAR(9), 
    sDataDate DATE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (sPropertyCode)
);

INSERT IGNORE Temp (sPropertyCode, sDataDate) 
SELECT sPropertyCode, sDataDate 
FROM tasks as t, task_data AS d 
WHERE t.iTaskId = d.iTaskId 
AND iRemoved = 1 
AND sDataType = 'sAgencyAgreementDate' 
AND iBusinessStreamId = 9;

SELECT t.sPropertyCode, sDataDate, SFirstSeen, sTaskType 
FROM tasks AS t, temp AS a 
WHERE iRemoved = 1 
AND iBusinessStreamId = 9 
AND sTaskType IN ('RF', 'IF', 'CM') 
AND t.sPropertyCode = a.sPropertyCode 
ORDER BY sPropertyCode, sFirstSeen;

DROP TABLE Temp;
```

So the references 'RF', 'IF' and 'CM' are tasks that we receive. Each propertycode can touch each of these tasks once, and only once. I would like to show the date that each one of these was touched by the propertycode. It is working at the moment but it is showing it in three columns with the tasks types in one column. I would like each task to show in a seperate column with the date it was first seen in its own corresponding column.

So from the picture below is how it is currently laid out with the code above.

[image]

And here is how I would like it to look, instead of the tasks showing down the side, I would like them to show accross in columns with their own specific dates

[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.sPropertyCode, sDataDate, SFirstSeen, a1.sTaskType, a2.sTaskType, a3.sTaskType
FROM tasks AS t
INNER JOIN temp AS a1 on t.sPropertyCode = a1.sPropertyCode and a1.sTaskType = 'RF'
INNER JOIN temp as a2 on t.sPropertyCode = a2.sPropertyCode and a2.sTaskType = 'IF'
INNER JOIN temp as a3 on t.sPropertyCode = a3.sPropertyCode and a3.sTaskType = 'CM' 
WHERE iRemoved = 1 AND iBusinessStreamId = 9
ORDER BY sPropertyCode, sFirstSeen;
```

You can also user outer join if not always have all 3 tast type.

Comment: Do I use this instead of my select code, still with the temp table created? as when I do that it says it cannot reopen a1.

Comment: Nebojsa Susic, This worked great. Im going to have to have a look at Inner/Outer joins so I understand them better. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

What is the difference in meaning between the CM,IF and RF columns for any row in your 5-col table ?  They're always the very same value in the example you listed.

Comment: It was just to show the layout but I used the information just so it populated as I didnt know how to populate it with the information that was correct. It was merely a visual aid

Comment: My question was intended to make you _think_ about your problem, which is usually the standard path to finding the solution, without any spoonfeeding.  Getting downvoted for it is of course not inspiring to help you out any further.

Comment: I didnt downvote as I dont have a good enough reputation. Thanks for your response though, I did learn from the above answer.